# C++ Macros and overloading

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, operators

I am working with c++ Macros, trying to implement on certain pattern. I have the following 3 macros:

```
#define First Objct t; t
#define Second a() / b()
#define Third ;
```

I've overload the lambda-ops in format: `Objct [ Objct ]`

So when I have in main() a line like:

```
First [ Second ] Third
```

it works fine, as it's 'translated' into:

```
Objct t; t[a()/b()]
```

(note: `a()` and `b()` are dummy functions returning type object.)

The hard part, is that I also have to make it work without the lambdas.

```
First Second Third
```

which means

```
Objct t; t a() / b()
```

In that case, I got a semicolon missing from `FIRST` to `SECOND`. I'm trying to figure out, what changes could be made (probably) to `FIRST` macro so it can compile in both cases.
I'm not sure if I managed to explain myself properly. Any ideas?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You have misunderstood the term "lambda". That's subscripting, or indexing.

Comment: You forgot to mention the purpose of this. It doesn't make sense. Voted  to close as unclear.

Comment: Neither of your examples shows the semicolon that comes from the expansion of `THIRD`.

Comment: Really sorry about that mess, I was just trying to simplify my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question in pretty strange. I would strongly advise you not to use such a weird construct in real code.  But I've looked at your question as if it were a funny puzzle.

**Potential solution**

I think there is no way to make both statement compile by changing only `First`.  But if you change `Second` to:

```
#define Second +0,a() / b()
```

it compiles in both cases, under the sole condition that operator `+` is defined for `Objct` in combination with an `int`. If you manage to implement this operator without side effect, it would even produce what you expect.

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/CBHEwl)

**Why does it work ?**

This definition makes use of the coma operator, the only issue being that the coma operator requires two expressions. +0 solves the issue syntactically, as `+0` alone is valid, and `t+0` is valid with the above-mentionned requirement.

With such a definition, `First Second Third` is preprocessed as

```
 Objct t; t +0,a() / b() ;     // comma operator evaluates t+0  
                               // then a()/b()
```

And `First [Second] Third` would be preprocessed as

```
 Objct t; t [+0,a() / b()] ;  // comma operator makes +0 being evaluated
                              // and lost and [] is called with value of a()/b().
```

Comment: That was extremely helpful actually. Works just fine. I changed Second to : `+1 / a() / b()` and overloaded + operator to accept obct + int so as to avoid the comma in the code. Thank you once again!